# Unity How to change the Rendering Order of A canvas

Tags: c#, cross-platform, unity-game-engine

I'm using unity 5.3 and I'm trying to change the Rendering Order of two overlayed cross platform controls which each reside in their own canvas.

In previous versions you could bring the window into focus using

```
GUI.FocusWindow(0);
```

However this does not work with the new system.
I've also tried modifying the order in the editor window which has done nothing.

Does anyone know how I can move a control to be on top of the other?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After doing some research I found the proper way to change the Canvas Rendering Order. There is a property in the Canvas for the Sort Order, which is really the render order.

[image].

Just as a note remember the controls you want to be on top should have a larger order than the control on bottom.

Answer (score 8):

Order in the editor window should work here. Are you sure you're changing the order of elements inside one canvas element?

Note that the order of elements in the Canvas game object is the order everything is rendered in - so the last thing you have in canvas will be the last thing drawn, so it will be on top of everything.

Here's how it works:
[image: editor window with canvas ordering example]

This is demonstrated with Unity 5.3.4, with much older Unity it can be different (there was a change of the way how children were enumerated somewhere in 5.0 or 5.1 AFAIK).

Comment: Originally, I swapped the order a few times which seemed to do nothing, I even made the controls children of one another, but has some weird effects,  but the scenario was a bit different the Joystick controls and the Dual touch Pad controls were children of their own elements special element. That reside in Standard Asset CrossPlatform Input Prefabs,  Maybe it was a canvas renamed, and I need to remove it from there.  I'll Investigate and post pictures when I get home, Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems to not work by order when there are multiple canvas's but luckily it turns out the parent object of the mobile controls were canvas's so i just moved the control and the mobile control script on the canvas i'm using and it's working now